# Ошибка ajax запроса в IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

Перед началом запроса у меня срабатывает beforeSend который ставит в элемент картинку загрузки, после того, как данные с сервера получены они вставляются в тот же элемент сайта.
Работает в FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome, а вот в ИЕ появляется только картинка загрузки и все, ничего не происходит
вот код

javascript:

```
 var log  = function(msg){
                console.log ? console.log(msg) : alert(msg);
            }
 function load(file, settings)  
{       
$('.body').ajaxStart(function(){ $('.body').html('<img src="http://vk.com/images/progress7.gif">'); });
$('.body').ajaxStop(function(){ log('Данные загружены!'); });
         $.ajax({
                url: file+".php",  
                cache: true,
                //scriptCharset: "CP1251",
                success: function(data){  
                    $('.body').html(data);  
                }  
            }); 
}
```

php:

```
   <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=cp1251');
    include ('db.php');
    $select = "SELECT * FROM links WHERE id=5";
        $pro = mysql_query($select, $dblink); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pro);
        echo $row['text'];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати, может, это именно ваш случай. Посмотрите, как отвечает в заголовках http сервер.

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Еси кодировка указана с ошибкой, скажем так

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf8
```

То ишак в этих случаях тупит.

Comment: @Arni у меня все стоит нормально, изначально всё работало, но в пхпэшках не стоял хидер и все данные получаемые были кракозяблями, поставил хидеры заработало, но потом решил поставить прогресс бар и все..все отказалось работать, кодировочка у меня везде стояла ср1251, если я даже поминяю на утф-8, то всё равно в IE не работает!

Comment: Все ребята, десяти часовые изменения закончены, проблема крылась в том, что в php файлах стол header с кодировкой ср1251, а надо было-то поставить кодировку windows-1251

Comment: Нет, ну нормально да? А я вам о чем говорил выше?

Comment: @Arni спасибо конечно за помощь, но у меня кодировка стояла не утф-8, а ср1251, про прикол с черточкой я тоже знал, но в данном случае он мне не помог, я решил поменять на windows-1251 и все заработало))))

Comment: Я utf-8, взял как пример. Старайтесь внимательнее читать, что вам советуют. )))

Comment: @Arni спасибо, в будущем буду внимательнее))☺

Comment: В будущем, также, старайтесь отмечать правильные ответы. В этом и есть весь смысл проекта hashcode )))

ps: я тоже ненавижу ишака.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы передаете html, то поставьте на сервере заголовок `"Content-Type: plain/text"`.

Comment: @aretmy поставил заголовки, и ничего не изменилось :(

Comment: Попробуйте text/plain еще

Comment: @aretmy, ничего не вышло.